# php form result loop

Tags: php, forms, loops

I'm trying to make a BASIC roulette script.

Is there anyway to get the submitted results of a form using PHP? In fact I know theres a way, but i can't find out how to do it.

So say if my form had several fields I want the result to loop through and show me which fields were filled and the numbers in each.

UPDATE: And say the form has about 40 fields, would I have to name each one in the loop? Any easier way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your form looks like this:

```
<form method="post" action="result.php">
    <input type="text" name="foo">
</form>
```

In `result.php` you can use the global variable `$_POST` and loop through it if you want:

```
foreach($_POST as $name => $value) {
    echo $name . ' = ' . $value;
}
```

If your form has 40 fields, you still need to name them all, but you can automate the process of naming and retrieving them with a loop. For example, if you wanted to create a sum with the value of all the fields, you could name them number1, number2, etc and do:

```
$sum = 0;
for($i = 1; $i <= 40; $i++)
    $sum += $_POST['number' . $i];
```

Answer (score 2):

$_GET or $_POST depending on the form method.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['formInputName'])){
  echo $_REQUEST['formInputName'];
}
```

$_REQUEST looks for GET, POST, and COOKIE.

You can also use $_GET to get a variable from the url (asdf.php?var=2).

Comment: Thanks, say theres about 40 odd fields though, would I have to check and name each one or is there an easier way?

Comment: It's advised to check each one, or using some prefix and check if the field (`if(substr($key, 0, 4) == "pre_") $_POST[$key]`) has it

Comment: Most importantly, you need to sanitize each user input.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the name of each field using `name="something"` in the `input` element, and than in the PHP you're getting it using `$_POST['something']` in case you sent the form as `method="post"` or `$_GET['something']` in case of get method

You can see what's sent using `var_dump()` or `print_r()`, just write something like that:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
```

Or you can go all over the array using foreach statement:

```
<?php
foreach($_POST AS $key=>$val)
{
    echo $key.': '.$val."<br />\n";
}
?>
```